# Failed to transform artifact 'localytics.aar"

Tags: android, gradle

After adding to gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I am receiving

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':videoplayer@unsignedUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform
>   artifact 'localytics.aar
>   (com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:localytics:1.3.0)' to
>   match attributes {artifactType=jar}.

This error occurs across all my modules. I need to include the androidX and Jetifier to gradle.properties. Any idea on how I can resolve this?

Here is what I have tried.

1) Add .arr to filetree

```
api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
```

2) Clean/Rebuild

3) Invalidate cache/restart

4) Confirmed that gradle offline work setting was disabled. I'm online!

5) Ignore Lint

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
```

Here is the gradle for one of the culprit modules

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion compileSdkVer

    defaultConfig {
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion minSdkVer
        targetSdkVersion targetSdkVer
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        // needed in this module for implementation/integration tests (tests in androidTest)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        unsigned {
            consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility targetCompatibilityVer
        sourceCompatibility sourceCompatibilityVer
    }

    aaptOptions {
        // ignore adding files, used for testing, to the apk
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!androidTest/**/*.json"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])

    androidTestImplementation(deps.espresso, {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation deps.junit

    api project(':commonuilib')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```